# Own Exception with IEnumerable<Exception>

Tags: c#, exception

I Want to make my own exception like `AggregateException` :

```
var exceptions = ErrorCollectionExtension.GetErrorsAsExceptions(compiler.Errors);
throw new AggregateException("Error", exceptions);
```

that can take as param `List` of `Exceptions`:

```
public MyException(string message, IEnumerable<Exception> innerExceptions)
        : base(message, innerExceptions)
    {

    }
```

But i get an error on `innerExceptions` in base.

How to make own exception with collection of it like `AggregateException`?

Comment: What's the base class of `MyException`? It'll be more useful if you share all the code for your exception class.

Comment: Are you extending `AggregateException` or `Exception`?

Comment: I just used `Exception` as my base class

Comment: Well, it's [been done](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/AggregateException.cs), so you could just peek at that for inspiration.

Comment: Any particular reason why you think that the built in `AggregateException` isn't a good fit for your needs?

Comment: `Exception` doesn't have an overload that takes a sequence of exceptions. You'll need to manage this sequence in your derived class, or just use the `AggregateException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to simply extend the `Exception` class by a collection of inner exceptions, somewhat like this:

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
    private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<Exception> _innerExceptions;

    public MyException(string message, IEnumerable<Exception> innerExceptions)
        : base(message, innerExceptions.FirstOrDefault())
    {
        _innerExceptions = innerExceptions.ToList().AsReadOnly();
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<Exception> InnerExceptions => _innerExceptions;
}
```

Alternatively you can just inherit from `AggregateException` and use its structure:

```
public class MyException : AggregateException
{

    public MyException(string message, IEnumerable<Exception> innerExceptions)
        : base(message, innerExceptions)
    {
    }
}
```